# DocumentDB LAMBDA SqlMethod.Like and .Contains NotImplemented Exception

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Im trying to do a simple "LIKE" query using a LAMBDA expression using `CreateDocumentQuery`; however after trying `.Contains` and `SqlMethod.Like` and both times receiving the response `NotImplementedException` I don't know what to try next!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update: As of [5/6/15](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/new-documentdb-sql-keywords-operators-and-functions/), DocumentDB added a set of String functions including `STARTSWITH`, `ENDSWITH`, and `CONTAINS`. Please note that most of these functions do not run on the index and will force a scan.**

`LIKE` and `CONTAINS` are not yet supported in DocumentDB.

You'll want to check out the [DocumentDB feedback page](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb) and vote on features (e.g. [LIKE](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6333414-implement-wildcards-when-searching) and [CONTAINS](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6333416-add-support-for-contains-within-documentdb-query-p)) to get your voice heard!

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've been and voted but I guessed those weren't supported by the exception. I'm asking if there is any OTHER way to get round it rather than pull the whole collection to the client and filter it there.

Comment: Depending on the size of the date you're dealing with - one potential workaround is to create a UDF to filter query results server-side. That caveat is UDFs have bounded execution time and do not take advantage of indices; you'll want avoid large scans (filter queries on indexed values whenever possible) and limit the amount of data passed to the UDF.

Comment: Please could cast your eye over my solution and perhaps feedback as to whether you think it would be a reasonable solution rather than as the UDF approach?

Answer (score 0):

Because I only needed to search against a discreet subset of properties of the larger object I implemented a `.Contains` search function as below. It works as expected though I have no idea regarding performance or scalability.

**Domain Models**

```
public interface ITaxonomySearchable
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
}

public class TaxonomySearchInfo : ITaxonomySearchable {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class TaxonomyContainer : ITaxonomySearchable
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "userId")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tags")]
    public string[] Tags { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "taxonomy")]
    public Node[] Taxonomy { get; set; }
}
```

**Search method**

```
public async static Task<List<TaxonomySearchInfo>> Search(string searchTerm)
{
    var db = GetJsonDocumentDb.GetDb();
    using (var client = GetJsonDocumentDb.GetClient())
    {
        var documentCollection = await GetJsonDocumentDb.GetDocumentCollection(db, client, "TaxonomyContainerCollection");
        return client.CreateDocumentQuery<TaxonomySearchInfo>(documentCollection.DocumentsLink)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Where(r => r.Name.Contains(searchTerm) || r.Description.Contains(searchTerm))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: The query in your search method looks like it will pass every document from the collection with a name or description attribute through the UDF - which may get costly depending on the number of documents that fit this criteria in your collection. You could try breaking up the query (one for name and one for description) and merging; as well as adding any additional filters/hints in the where clause whenever possible. Try running the query and make sure # of RU's consumed in the x-ms-request-charge header is acceptable.

Comment: There's a pretty good tool floating around called DocumentDB Studio, that makes trying out queries and examining response/headers fairly easy...  Link: https://github.com/mingaliu/DocumentDBStudio/releases

Comment: Thanks so much for reviewing this and the tip about DocumentDB studio - very much appreciated!